# Getting repeated values in jquery token field ,how to avoid those repeated values

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hello everyone i am working with jquery tokenfield ,in that getting same user name multiple times so i want it should come only once below i had posted my code can you tell me how to avoid duplicate values.
[getting same values repeatedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkBvH.png)

Below code for tokenfield in script with text box. i am using codeigniter framework.

```
<input type="text" name="txt" class="get_username">

<script>
function get_token_field() {
    $('.get_username').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
            source: "<?= base_url('controller/method name') ?>",
            delay: 100
        },
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
}
</script>
```

Below script in Codeigniter controller

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $name = strtolower($_GET['term']);
    $this->model_name->get_user_names($name);
}
```

Below script in Codeigniter Model

```
public function get_user_names($name) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');

    $this->db->like('username', $name);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $test[] = $row['username'];

        }
        echo json_encode($test); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code it will check your existing token and if you entering double it will prevent.

```
  $('.get_username').on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (event) {
        var tokens = $(this).tokenfield('getTokens');
        $.each(tokens, function(index, token) {
            if (token.value === event.attrs.value)
                event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello friends i tried this one but still its not working.

Comment: i am calling one function which will look for tokenfield so after calling function i have included your script and removed my script,but this time not getting a single value

Comment: @MSp don't remove your script just add it below of it. https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield

Comment: thanks for your answer its working fine,now one more thing is that if have  i two different person  with same name example:1)sumesh, 2)sumesh it is selecting only one person name but ignoring last person, but their id is different plz tell me how to get both person even they have same name.

Comment: @MSp you are binding just username in textbox, so can't get id or what is purpose of id and this field. you can't bind id and person name in textbox like this.

Comment: @MSp  did you checked my answer?

Comment: @Ahmed Ginani both persons are different but their name is same and in list  names are getting one by one so i want to select that different persons having same name.

Comment: @Alive to Die yes i had checked your answer but didn't get ,so i made some changes in script now its working .after calling  script again i had bind another script which is suggested by ahmed Ginani .

Comment: @Alive to Die, but if i have different persons with same name than  not able to select that one also

Comment: @MSp  in that case using above code also you are not able to do that because same name will replaced and it comes only one through above script too.